# How to compare 2 button backgrounds in Android?

Tags: android, background

So I have 2 buttons (or ImageButtons or even anything that can use a background) with the same background. I want a method to check whether they have the same background or not.

I tried 2 buttons with the **same background**, this

```
button1.getBackground();
button2.getBackground();
```

But they both returned **different values**.

Any other methods?

Comment: your background is a color or a drawable resources?

Comment: w drawable resource ( picture of an apple )

Answer (score 1):

The `getBackground()` method returns a `Drawable` object.

Now to compare two `Drawable` objects its best to use the `getConstantState()` method to obtain them. This should work.

```
button1.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(button2.getBackground().getConstantState())
```

Comment: Welcome. Accept an answer to close the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with tags, You can use tags in order to compare the background drawables .

```
    btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    btn.setTag(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Then you can get the tag with ,

```
    btn.getTag();
```

and compare them.